# CSS to child p tag not getting applied based on parent div's class

Tags: html, css

I have to apply different styles to p tag which is created under to 2 seprate divs.

```css
.wrapper .extraclass p{
  color: green;
}

.wrapper .class1 p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="class1 class2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="extraclass class1 class2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The color for both p's is same. How can I reorganize my css to make this work?

Comment: There are a lot of answers now... Whichever you choose, just make sure you close the `<div>` tags correctly with `</div>`

Comment: Thanks @PatrickManser. Noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put you css in this way, so it can override above global css,

```
.wrapper .class1 p{
  color: red;
}
.wrapper .extraclass p{
  color: green;
}
```

`.wrapper .class1 p` will select all p tags within `.class1` if you want to override css of `.extraclass p` you have to put it after `.wrapper .class1 p` css

```css
.wrapper .class1 p {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper .extraclass p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class1 class2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   <div>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="extraclass class1 class2">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have both .extraclass and .class1 in the lasp p-tag
Try reorder them so it says " class1 class2 extraclass".
If not then you might have to remove class1 form the last p-tag.
Or you can always put !important behind the "color: red" but I would not recommend this :)

Comment: Thanks. The markup is auto generated. I have no control over the class addition into the div.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS was fine.. I just restructured your HTML a bit:

```css
.wrapper .extraclass p {
  color: green;
}

.wrapper .class1 p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class1 class2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="extraclass"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum 
    neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit 
    massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I took out the class1 from extraclass and corrected the unclosed `<div>s`

Look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeRKJZ

Comment: Thanks but I cannot change the markup. Its autogenerated. I can only play with css.

Comment: Okay, just for the next time: That's something you should mention in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give the correct priority of style
the below class will override upper class

```css
.wrapper .class1 p{
  color: red;
}

.wrapper .extraclass p{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="class1 class2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<div>
<div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="extraclass class1 class2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second class definition overrode the first when being applied to `p`.  I recommend having one definition for classes that will always have shared properties (using `.wrapper` or something else) and peculiar properties in another `class` or `id`.

Also, please make better use of indenting and use `</div>` to close off a `div`.

```css
.extraclass
{
     color: blue;
}

.class1
{
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="class1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="extraclass">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc condimentum neque eu mauris eleifend, eget dapibus diam pulvinar. Curabitur hendrerit massa ut dui ultrices.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```